# Pasar de texto a nombre de variable

Tags: jquery

Tengo una textbox en la que el ususario inserta un texto y despues quisiera, por codigo, crear una variable con dicho texto. ¿como podria hacerlo?.

Comment: Seleccionas el contenido de donde esté el texto y lo asignas a una variable.

Comment: ¿Y qué has probado de hacer? Esta web no es un "Quiero esto pero no se como hacerlo, ¿me lo hacéis?". Trae algo que hayas hecho, sino funciona, aquí te ayudaremos a resolverlo

Comment: perdon, no me he explicado bien, si en el texbox insertan por ejemplo: "labrador", quisiera crear una variable que se llame labrador. para luego usarla del modo labrador='negro'.

Comment: Quieres decir, que si tengo `var miVariable = ""` y alguien pone "labrador", el nombre de `miVariable` pase a `labrador` o que el contenido de `miVariable` sea labrador. Porque si es lo primero, olvídate de ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar un array para poder hacerlo:

```js
$variable = [];

$input = $('.texto').text();

$variable[$input] = "negro";

console.log($variable[$input]);
console.log($variable["labrador"]);
console.log($variable.labrador); // que es la opcion que buscaba y que tambien se puede hacer con objetos.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textbox class="texto">labrador</textbox>
```

Comment: El op quiere un input o textarea que al darle a un botón el texto quede en una variable.

Comment: Edito respuesta según lo pedido.

Comment: Lo puse cuando vi que estaba mal, ahora que está bien, lo retiro, además, sigue sin responder al op, eso simplemente lo hará al cargar la página, no cuando el usuario escriba algo

Comment: Lo que ha preguntado es cómo crear una variable con el nombre que el usuario indica, y éste código lo hace. Que luego él lo quiera recoger mediante un botón/contador/evento... es cosa suya.

Answer (score 0):

Cheshire: efectivamente lo que queria era lo primero, crear una variable que se llamase igual que lo que el ususario habia insertado en el texbox.

Lo he solucionado creando un objeto vacio y añadiendo despues una propiedad con el nombre que se inserto en el texbox.